# How to check if checkboxes of gridview are checked?

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0, gridview

`enter code here`I have a Gridview with each rows containing 5 Checkbox with names 'NO','YES','NA','NA/U' and 'REPEAT'. I want to enable a button if any one checkbox amoung 'NO' 'YES' 'NA' or 'NA/U' checkbox of all rows are checked. How I can i achieve this functionality. Javascript will be better or C#? Help me with this

' runat="server">
                                        
                                    
                                    
                                        
                                    
                                    
                                        
                                    
                                    
                                        
                                            
                                            <%--

Comment: Post your code here pls

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse javasript/jquery will be better. You can find your checked checkboxes in row of gridview and match that count with the rows of gridview.

Use below syntax to find checked checkboxes in row of your gridview.

```
$("[id$='GridID'] tr td input[type=checkbox]:checked");
```